# Low speed SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have 16000 rows in SQL Server and I want to assign document number physically to the records and using following code, it works fine but lazy when my records was 8000 but when the records increases to 16000 it gives me a time out error, please help me to increase the performance of my query ???

```
declare @NewDoc int;
set @NewDoc=0
declare t1_cursor cursor dynamic for select  documentheaderid,documentnumber from Accounting.DocumentHeader where FinancialPeriodFK=@FinancialPeriodFK and Date>=@FromDate and Date<=@ToDate order by Date
open t1_cursor

fetch next from t1_cursor
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
set @NewDoc=@NewDoc+1;


update  Accounting.DocumentHeader set DocumentNumber=@NewDoc where current of t1_cursor
fetch next from t1_cursor
end 
close t1_cursor
deallocate t1_cursor
```

Comment: @marc_s what do you mean by Set-based operation ?

Comment: Set-based means **avoiding** RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing - like using a cursor or a while loop. You tell SQL Server **what you want** - but not in detail how to do it and let SQL Server decide how to solve the problem for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this - **avoiding** any **row-by-agonizing-row** processing like a cursor or a while loop:

```
-- creates a temporary "inline" view of the data you're interested in and 
-- assigns each row a consecutive number
;WITH DataToUpdate AS
(
    SELECT
        DocumentHeaderId,
        DocumentNumber,
        NewDocNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM
        Accounting.DocumentHeader
    WHERE
        FinancialPeriodFK = @FinancialPeriodFK
        AND Date >= @FromDate
        AND Date <= @ToDate
)
-- update the base table to make use of that new document number 
UPDATE dh
SET dh.DocumentNumber = dtu.NewDocNum
FROM Accounting.DocumentHeader dh
INNER JOIN DataToUpdate dtu ON dh.DocumentHeaderId = dtu.DocumentHeaderId
```

That should **significantly** speed up your processing time!

Comment: Thanks dear @marc_s , it improves the speed unbelievably from 80sec to 2sec .< GOOD JOB >